# General form of Tutte polynomial for a family of graphs

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, graph-invariants

I'm looking at a family of graphs that look like this:

$n = 1$

[image: n=1]

$n = 2$

[image: n=2]

$n = 3$

[image: n=3]

So for every $n$ you add another "shell" and connect it with the previous outer shell.

What i'm interested in is if there is a nice way to express the Tutte polynomial of these graphs for every $n$.

Due to the restrictions set by [this paper](https://mat-web.upc.edu/people/anna.de.mier/tesidina4.pdf) in theorem 1.17 I have a hunch that all the graphs in this family are T-unique and I would like to study the polynomial further. Any help is much appreciated!

The Tutte polynomials for the first three family members look like this:
$$T_{G_{n=1}}(x,y) = x^3+x^2+x+y$$

$$T_{G_{n=2}}(x,y) = {x}^{7}+5\,{x}^{6}+15\,{x}^{5}+6\,{x}^{4}y+{y}^{5}+29\,{x}^{4}+24\,{x}
^{3}y+12\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+8\,x{y}^{3}+7\,{y}^{4}+40\,{x}^{3}+52\,{x}^{2
}y+39\,x{y}^{2}+20\,{y}^{3}+32\,{x}^{2}+46\,xy+25\,{y}^{2}+11\,x+11\,y
$$

$$T_{G_{n=3}}(x,y) = {x}^{11}+9\,{x}^{10}+45\,{x}^{9}+11\,{x}^{8}y+2\,{x}^{4}{y}^{5}+{y}^{9
}+154\,{x}^{8}+88\,{x}^{7}y+28\,{x}^{6}{y}^{2}+16\,{x}^{5}{y}^{3}+14\,
{x}^{4}{y}^{4}+8\,{x}^{3}{y}^{5}+8\,{x}^{2}{y}^{6}+8\,x{y}^{7}+11\,{y}
^{8}+396\,{x}^{7}+376\,{x}^{6}y+223\,{x}^{5}{y}^{2}+144\,{x}^{4}{y}^{3
}+108\,{x}^{3}{y}^{4}+92\,{x}^{2}{y}^{5}+78\,x{y}^{6}+58\,{y}^{7}+784
\,{x}^{6}+1030\,{x}^{5}y+833\,{x}^{4}{y}^{2}+624\,{x}^{3}{y}^{3}+484\,
{x}^{2}{y}^{4}+356\,x{y}^{5}+192\,{y}^{6}+1203\,{x}^{5}+1964\,{x}^{4}y
+1892\,{x}^{3}{y}^{2}+1495\,{x}^{2}{y}^{3}+1000\,x{y}^{4}+441\,{y}^{5}
+1395\,{x}^{4}+2580\,{x}^{3}y+2591\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+1786\,x{y}^{3}+715
\,{y}^{4}+1148\,{x}^{3}+2149\,{x}^{2}y+1869\,x{y}^{2}+777\,{y}^{3}+589
\,{x}^{2}+948\,xy+498\,{y}^{2}+139\,x+139\,y$$

Comment: The obvious approach to this problem is to use transfer matrices. Biggs has two papers ("Specht modules and chromatic polynomials", JCT B, 2004 and "A Matrix Method for Flow Polynomials", http://www.cdam.lse.ac.uk/Reports/Files/cdam-2008-08.pdf) which apply this technique to chromatic and flow polynomials.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it.